# PhpMailer not working with html

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using `PhpMailer` class to send emails that contains html,I noticed that if the body on email contain `img` tags the email not receiving and no errors showing.

Any suggestions?

my code so far:

```
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->Port = 465;

            $mail->Username = "myusername";
            $mail->Password = "mypassword";


                $mail->setFrom($from);
                $mail->addAddress($to);

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body =$body;
            $mail->IsHTML(true); 

            if ($mail->send()) {
                return 1;
            } else {

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: It sometimes happens that email providers (e.g. outlook) block images in emails. The might even be treated as spam. What provider are you trying to send to?

Comment: If you remove image tag, is that working?

Comment: can you post your php mailer class code

Comment: @SudharshanNair yes if i remove the img tags it is working

Comment: @Chris to gmail account

Comment: @HaiderAli check the class code

Comment: What does the body variable contains?

Comment: html content @HaiderAli

Comment: email successful  received   to outlook it seems the issue on gmail account

Comment: Gmail can be very fickle, and sometimes over-zealous in its spam protection. Have you tried simply altering the names of the images, or routes to them, or just embedding them? Something about your body with image tags is tripping something on their side. It could even be the domain hosting the images is new, it's almost alchemy figuring out how to make them happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're trying to send it from localhost and read in gmail, it won't work because gmail often creates proxy image links. you need to send image links that direct to internet-accessible location. That's probably it.
If you're sending email with links to internet-accessible locations, please attach them to the question and I'll update the answer, too.

EIDT: after chat with the asker, it was determined the email HTML was missing normal HTML markup: `<html><body>ACTUALCONTENT</body></html>`, after adding those,image shown up correctly.

Comment: Yes I am sending from online website

Comment: please add the email contents, then, and lets see what's wrong with it

Comment: <br>
  <div class="item clearfix">
   <div class="itemimg">
     <img src="path-to-image"/>
   </div>
   <div class="itemtext">
     <h3>title</h3>
     <p>description</p>
     <p class="price">price</p>
     <a  class="more-d" href="link-to-page">More details...</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br>

Comment: "path-to-image" isn't a valid image resource, please do not replace the non-working part. it is crucial for us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: <br> <div class="item clearfix"> <div class="itemimg"> <img src=http://waveintlgt.com/uploads/download-1.jpg /> </div> <div class="itemtext"> <h3>title</h3> <p>description</p> <p class="price">price</p> <a class="more-d" href="link-to-page">More details...</a> </div> </div> <br>

Comment: the link should have a protocol in it. either `http://`, `https://` or protocol-relative `//` although I'm not sure how is your email client handling those. so safest bet is `https://` please add it to the link, send another email and check again. Otherwise it's relative path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178185/discussion-between-janmyszkier-and-mhmd-backer-shehadi).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AddEmbeddedImage` method to attach image to your body. So your code should look like this.

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($_REQUEST['image_name'], 'ImageName');
```

And then in your $body you can use this image

```
$body.= "<img src='cid:ImageName' />";
```